# Intel AX210 with single antenna saw 5Ghz and then it didn't?

Tags: wifi, iwlwifi, connectivity

I've been upgrading an a bit older HP Pavillion laptop with SSD, more RAM and since I had one lying around, an Intel AX210 m2 wifi adapter.

The stock adapter was a single-channel Broadcom BCM943142YHN_2 and to my surprise it had only a single antenna connected, to its right connecter (seen from the m2 connector side). After staring hard at the labels near the connectors I concluded that I'd have to connect that antenna to the Intel's left connector (a quick search on which port is which on each adapter turned up empty - or rather, floaded with irrelevancy).

I flipped the laptop, turned it on without closing it (countless plastic tabs and 24 screws!), booted into Linux and LO AND BEHOLD I had dual channel wifi. In Win10 too, after installing the appropriate drivers. This confirmed what I had been told when I ordered the AX210 for another laptop which does have 2 antennas but also only a single-channel adapter: these are just wires and should work with both frequency ranges. In fact, in that system one of the antennas seems rather to be for bluetooth - I have no need for that so as far as I'm concerned I also don't need an antenna for it.

I think 5Ghz connectivity continued to work until yesterday evening, but this morning it's gone after a reboot.

Laptop hasn't been moved and the antenna connected with a very definite snap so I doubt it can have come lose or develop a bad contact overnight.

To me it doesn't really make sense. The 5Ghz signal is strong enough at this location to pick up and it is when I plug in the external RTL-based dongle I'd hoped to eliminate, or by my phone.

**Any ideas what could explain why it no longer works, or why it worked yesterday?**

Is it possible that the HP BIOS (InsydeH20 v F81) has detected that I put in an "unsupported" wifi module and cut off 5Ghz access (it's still visible in the properties tab of Win10's device manager)?
Annoyingly HP disabled the "advanced" BIOS settings, for "security reasons", so I cannot for instance disable the bluetooth function at the lowest level as I'd prefer.

**Also, does anyone have pointers for finding out which antenna connector is which on both adapters?**

Comment: Current kernel in use is 5.10.x-xanmod1 which is the first to have AX210 support according to https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html . I'm building a 5.15 xanmod1 kernel as we speak and will update the firmware but I don't expect much difference as far as wifi is concerned - Win10 already has even an more up-to-date driver and shows the same problem.

Comment: So indeed, the kernel change and the latest firmware don't make much difference. What does make a difference is moving the laptop into the same room as the wifi router.

Comment: I got a RealTek 8821au based USB dongle to work, one without external/visible antenna. It sees the available 2.4Ghz networks at the same signal strength as the AX210 does with its wire antenna that's routed behind the display panel. But it also sees the 5Ghz networks, and mine has actually about 10% more signal strength than the 2.4Ghz one...